# Does this character die in Jurassic World: Fallen Kingdom?

Tags: plot-explanation, jurassic-world-fallen-kingdom

In *Jurassic World: Fallen Kingdom* Franklin stabs Dr. Henry Wu in the neck with a syringe of some sort just after Zia tells Dr. Wu that Blue's blood has been contaminated with blood from Rexy.

Was Dr. Wu knocked out or killed?

One of the mercenaries then carries away his body just before the mercenary gets taken out by Blue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, Dr. Wu doesn't die. He is just knocked out.

That syringe was for tranquilizing dinosaurs. The same syringe is used by Ken Wheatley to knock out Owen when he meets Blue in the jungle.

Dr. Zia says this when they try to locate dinosaurs,

> These are powerful sedatives. One too many, and she could
>   have respiratory failure.

You can even see the color of that liquid for neutralization is same.

When Dr. Wu was being carried away, mercenaries gets killed by Blue, but he wasn't shown getting killed. So, it is safe to assume that he is alive.

Comment: The problem with that answer is that the mercenary wasn't gone long enough to get Dr. Wu out of danger from the gas that was going to kill the dinosaurs. For me I assume he died in the gas unless someone else drug him to safety.

Comment: So, enough tranquillizer to down a dinosaur somehow won't be enough to kill a human?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that he got killed by the syringe, but surely the whole place exploded moments afterwards? The mercenaries didn't have enough time to drag him out of the way of the blast zone and come back to fight blue afterwards.